# Mutliple fields in the where clause of a QuerySet

Tags: django, django-queryset

In a e-shop application I have a model for storing history of order processing:

```
class OrderStatusHistory(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='status_history')
    status = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now I want to get most recent status for each order. In pure SQL I can do this in a single query:

```
select * from order_orderstatushistory where (order_id, date) in (select order_id, max(date) from order_orderstatushistory group by order_id)
```

What is the best way do this in Django?

I have two options. The first is:

```
# Get the most recent status change date for each order
v = Order.objects.annotate(Max('status_history__date')).values_list('id', 'status_history__date__max')

# Get OrderStatusHistory objects
hist = OrderStatusHistory.objects.extra(where=['(order_id, date) IN %s'], params=[tuple(v)])
```

And the second:

```
hist = OrderStatusHistory.objects.extra(where=['(order_id, date) IN (select order_id, max(date) from order_orderstatushistory group by order_id)'])
```

The first option is pure Django, but results in 2 database queries and a large list of parameters passed from Django to database engine.

The second option requires to put SQL code directly into my application, but I'd like to avoid this.

Is there equivalent of `where (order_id, date) in (select ...)` in Django?

Comment: why can't you do something like: OrderStatusHistory.objects.annotate(max_date=Max('order__status_history__date'))

Comment: James, thank you for your answer, but I can't figure out how it can help me to get most recent status for each order.
And in general, I'd like to know if it's possible to write something like "where (order_id, date) in (select ...)" in Django.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this query

```
OrderStatusHistory.objects.order_by('order', '-date').distinct('order')
```

Comment: I moved from django 1.3 to django 1.4 and solved this problem by using `Orders.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related('status_history')` and then `self.status_history.all()[self.status_history.count() - 1].status`